# Passing arguments to a .NET exe file with _spawnv

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c, arguments

I am working with a software that uses the _spawnv and _spawnve functions to call other exe files. Now this works correctly if I call a C or C++ exe file, but when I try to call a .NET exe file (C#)  I always miss the first argument that I have passed to the exe file, as an example if I send these arguments

1.1.1.1, 20, i@domain.com, yes, no

in the .NET app it will log the arguments as

20, i@domain.com, yes, no

and I get an FormatException because of the email string. Now I can just add a dummy argument, but since I do not understand why this is happening I would rather not do it.

So the question is why am I missing the first argument in the .NET application.

cheers,
es

Comment: First argument (zero-index one) is a full path to exe-file afair.

Comment: I just looked at the _spawnv doc and yes you are correct, but I don't understand why it works with a non .NET app but not a .net app.

Comment: How do you read the arguments in the .NET app?